# apex:repeat with Save button, saves only first record in it

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, repeat, apex-param

I have an apex:repeat with Child Name and Edit button displayed. (3 children in the list) **ListMember**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listMember}" var="member">
     <label>Name</label>
     <apex:commandLink>Edit
         <apex:param name="fieldName" value="{!member.name}"/>
     </apex:commandLink>
</apex:repeat>
```

On click of Edit button I open the below inputField with Save button. **ListM**.  The correct child is opened based on the rendering condition of **FieldName** that is being passed.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listM}" var="child">  
      <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!($CurrentPage.parameters.fieldName == Child.name)}">
           <apex:form> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!child.Name}" id="childNewName"/>                                   
                   <apex:commandLink action="{!updateHFProfile}">
                     <apex:commandButton value="Save"/>
                     <apex:param name="pramvalue" assignTo="{!pramvalue}" value="memberRecords"/>                                            
                   </apex:commandLink>
            </apex:form>      
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

**ISSUE** After editing the 'Child 1' name and clicking on SAVE, it is correctly updating the child name.  But if I Update Child 2 or Child 3, the name is not being saved!!  What could be the issue here?

Apex class

```
public String pramvalue{get;set{pramvalue=value;}}
public PageReference updateHFProfile(){
   update updatMembersList;
}

     public list<Member__c> updatMembersList{get;set;}
     public list<Member__c> listM{
        get{
            List<Member__c> listlocal;
            listlocal=[Select Id,NameFrom Member__c where Account_Name__c=: profileId__c];
            if(listlocal!=null && listlocal.size()>0){
                System.debug('members size--->'+listlocal.size());                
                updatMembersList = listlocal;
            }
    return listlocal;
        }
       set;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the issue.  It is because of `<apex:form>` inside the apex:repeat.  It is treating as new form for every record.  I put the `<apex:form>` outside of the `<apex:repeat>`

```
<apex:form>
<apex:repeat value="{!listM}" var="child">  
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <!--ETC -->
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `repeat` to use `updatMembersList`:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!updatMembersList}" var="child">
```

---

You don't really need two separate `List<Member>` properties, though. The problem is, your `getter` for `listM` overwrites the results every call. The Lazy Load Pattern can fix this issue. Try replacing `updatMembersList` and `listM` with one list that looks like:

```
public List<Member__c> children
{
    get
    {
        if (children == null)
        {
            // INITIALIZATION LOGIC HERE
            // You only want to run it once
        }
        return children;
    }
    private set;
}
public PageReference updateHFProfile(){
   update children;
}
```

Comment: that didn't help

Comment: I knew No issue with controller, because the first record was saving anyways.  Figured out the issue with VF.  It is because of the extra <apex:form>.  Thanks anyways for looking into this @Adrian Larson

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy fair enough. You still don't really need two lists though.